# Description that sets the scene in a play

Tags: terminology

In plays, there is often a description at the beginning of the scene that sets the scene before the characters start speaking. e.g., see the paragraph in italics [here](http://www.bartleby.com/138/1.html). What is the formal term for it?

Answer (score 1):

The stage writing term is *At Rise Description*, so called because it describes the scene as it should look when the curtains lift. In screenwriting it is more commonly simply called a *scene description*, and follows the *slugline*.

In the example you gave the italicized text in the second paragraph is not part of the at rise description, but is rather an *action direction*.

Comment: I don't dispute the truth of anything you say, but it's all entirely unsupported. You should include links for definitions and/or usages.